# Windows "Computer Locked" default dialog positioning?

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to edit this value so that it isn't in the middle of the screen?  I would like it off in the corner in order to avoid obscuring my wallpaper.

Answer (score 4):

If you ask Microsoft, the answer will be "this is by design and cannot be changed".
However, if you feel very adventurous, then I found this on the web. 
I take no responsibility and don't vouch for its correctness.
**It may answer your question or destroy your boot**.

a. Install [Recovery Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058/)

b. Downolad a copy of [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

c. Find "msgina.dll" under \windows\system32 and copy it to the root (C:) folder

d. Start ResourceHacker and open msgina.dll from the root

e. Under Dialog-1900 replace the dialog with this one:

> 1900 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 0, 0 
>   STYLE WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE 
>   CAPTION ""
>   LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH,SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
>   FONT 0, ""
>   {
>   }

f. Hit "Compile Script" and save it (an original of your msgina.dll was saved automatically under C:\ with the name "msgina_original.dll")

g. Restart the computer and choose Recovery Console at start up

h. Copy the new .dll into "\windows\system32" and "\windows\system32\dllcache" (hit "y" when it asks for rewriting existing file)

these are the commands:

> copy c:\msgina.dll
>   c:\windows\system32\ 
>   copy c:\msgina.dll
>   c:\windows\system32\dllcache

i. type "exit"

j. Now when your Windows restarted and you Lock your computer there will not be any pop-up window. To unlock just simply hit ALT+CTRL+DEL

Comment: Nice find , hope it doesn't crash xp :)

Comment: Very Interesting. Since the target machine is my work computer, I'll probably wait to test it on one of my own machines :)

Comment: The things people are willing to spend their time on . . .

Answer (score 2):

Not easily as far as I know.

You can manually edit the GINA, but you may be heading down a bad path if you do that!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx

There are millions of resources on this, they all seem to be as cryptic as each other so I cannot recommend one of another.

Comment: Jebus...talk about killing a fly with an axe.